# How to set min-height of slider carousel equal to the varying height of image?

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set min-height of carousel to the varying size of image. Note: the image reduces by height when the window shrinks.

I tried to use java-script to set height of carousel equal to the height of image. But the problem is the height is constant for all the window sizes. What I didn't find was to provide dynamic value to the height based on responsiveness.

What I am doing seems little silly but I am having an issue. Issue is slider carousel takes time loading which results to lower components taking the position of slider for a glimpse. That ruins the appearance of my site. In order to solve that particular issue, I thought of setting up min-height of slider carousel to certain height. Doing that ruins responsiveness because in lower screen additional space is generated below slider. So only solution is setting min-height of slider to the varying height of image based on window size. There might be other methods as well for which I would highly appreciate.

```
// Js
const sliderImage = document.querySelector(".slider-image");
const slider = document.querySelector(".carousel");
slider.style.minHeight = sliderImage.height + "px";

// HTML
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide placeholder" data- 
ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{url('image/slider/slider02.jpg')}}" 
      class="slider-image d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{url('image/slider/slider01.jpg')}}" class="d-block w- 
      100" 
      alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{url('image/slider/slider03.jpg')}}" class="d-block w- 
      100" 
      alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
  role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" 
  role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

// No css applied yet
```

Comment: Hi @Bipin please could you also share your HTML and styles for a complete picture.

Comment: @MikePoole I provided html code which I took from bootstrap. No css applied yet.

Comment: Are you using Angular @Bipin? If so have you tested you can get the height of `image/slider/slider02.jpg` from the DOM e.g. `console.log(document.querySelector(".slider-image"));`?

Comment: @MikePoole Additionally there was a small error in my html code. I used multiple class property in my img tag. However I edited now. But that doesn't solve the issue :)

Comment: Ahh, well that is bad form. Instead of `class="slider-image" class="d-block w-100"` roll them all into a single class attribute like this `class="slider-image d-block w-100"`.

Comment: @MikePoole Nope sir, I am not using Angular. I am using laravel balde.

Comment: Right, I suspected you were using an extra framework because of the curly braces in your src attributes. You really need to check that the JavaScript can get to the correct height of the image so it can then use it. Keep it simple and first of all check if you can get the height of the image from your DOM.

Comment: @MikePoole I am getting the height of image. But as mentioned above, the height is static. What I want is the dynamic responsive height of image. I am struggling finding out the correct resource for this particular problem.

Comment: To clarify what you want to do is it that you want to set the min-height of the image container to be the same as the height of the image container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199407/discussion-between-bipin-and-mike-poole).

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments I take your question to be how you set the min-height of the image container to be the same as the height of the image container.

Your JavaScript should be changed so it looks up the height of the `.carousel-item` (i.e. the container of the image) rather than of `.slider-image`:

```
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".carousel-item");
const slider = document.querySelector(".carousel");
slider.style.minHeight = sliderContainer.height + "px";
```

Note that this assumes there are no other `.carousel-item` instances on the page. If that is likely to be the case then you should use ID's (e.g. `#carouselItem`) rather than the class name as a reference.

Comment: console says the height of sliderContainer is undefined

Comment: using offsetHeight instead of height does it. Thanks for the help @Mike. But still I am experiencing the glimpse :( because the height of carousel-item is 0 for the very first time when the site loads. Maybe I should find the other way around to solve the major issue.

Comment: Yes, offsetHeight would work. At the end of the day though I am not sure why you want to do this. Why not just set a min-height of say 50px?

Comment: Because that would ruin the responsiveness. In lower screens, there exists some white space after slider